# Closed but edited review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, closed-questions

Thousands of new questions arrive at Stack Overflow every day. In the first minutes the questions get viewed the most and if bad/unclear/off-topic downvoted and closed as such.

If the OP later edits the post these people are gone and closed questions mostly stay like that - closed.

Could we introduce a new review queue to make these posts more prominent? In there questions would go that are closed, but edited **by the OP**. This way they get another shot at reopening.

<sub>One related solution for this is [notifying downvoters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c) after an edit.</sub>

Comment: "**by the OP**", I do always think it's a bit of a shame when a question comes into the reopen queue due to a spelling correction edit from some other user.

Comment: Aren't these already put in the reopen queue? Edit: Yes, if they're edited within 5 days of being closed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/1288

Comment: Same thing happened with my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432966/how-to-know-which-of-the-n-regexes-matched-the-string

Comment: @BilltheLizard Should we ask a new question rather than editing, cleaning and rephrasing a closed question ??

Comment: @Amit If it's *your* closed question, you should definitely edit it rather than posting a duplicate. If it was someone else's question, I'd just make an effort to formulate a better question when you ask a new one.